# Renaming keys in a Dict[str, Any]

Tags: python

Given a `Dict[str, Any]` and a mapping of "key paths" to new names, produce a new `dict` in the shape of the original that uses the new names while preserving everything else.

## Example

Let's say this is the original `dict`:

```py
d = {
    "id": 1,
    "summary": {
        "origin": {
            "url": "https://www.google.com/",
            "slug": "google"
        },
        "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "abc",
            "price": 50
        },
        {
            "id": "def",
            "price": 110,
            "discount": 50
        }   
    ]
}
```

The following should be produced:

```py
newd = {
    "IDENTIF": 1,
    "SUMM": {
        "ORIG": {
            "WEBADDRESS": "http://www.google.com/",
            "LOCATOR": "google"
        },
        "TAGS": ["tag1", "tag2"]
    },
    "PURCHASEDGOODS": [
        {
            "GOODSID": "abc",
            "GOODSPRICE": 50
        },
        {
            "GOODSID": "def",
            "GOODSPRICE": 110,
            "GIVENDISCOUNT": 50
        }   
    ]
}
```

It is important that if the original `dict` had been `{"items": {"id": "123"}}`, the produced `dict` must be `{"PURCHASEDGOOD": {"id": "123"}}` because in the required replacement scheme, `"id"` is replaced with `"GOODSID"` only if it occurs as a key of a `dict` that is an element of a `list` under `"items"`.

### My solution

The user of the code is supposed to call the `mapped_to_fields` function which is at the very bottom.

```py
from typing import Tuple, Dict

# Maps a path in a dictionary (a key path) to a key name. For
# example, the mapping ("a", "b", "c") -> "d" maps the nested "c" in
# {"a": {"b": {"c": "this one"}}, "c": "not this one"} to a string
# "d". LIST denotes a list nested within a dict:
# ("one", LIST, "two") -> "x" will map every "two" in
# {"one": [{"two": "val1"}, {"two": "val2"}]} to "x".
LIST = ""
FIELD_MAP = {
    ("id",):                        "IDENTIF",
    ("summary",):                   "SUMM",
    ("summary", "origin"):          "ORIG",
    ("summary", "origin", "url"):   "WEBADDRESS",
    ("summary", "origin", "slug"):  "LOCATOR",
    ("summary", "tags"):            "TAGS",
    ("items",):                     "PURCHASEDGOODS",
    ("items", LIST, "id"):          "GOODSID",
    ("items", LIST, "price"):       "GOODSPRICE",
    ("items", LIST, "discount"):    "GIVENDISCOUNT"
}


def mapped_to_fields_list(l: list, field_map: Dict[Tuple[str], str], parent: Tuple[str]) -> list:
    result = list()

    for val in l:
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            result.append(mapped_to_fields(val, field_map, parent))
        elif isinstance(val, list):
            result.append(mapped_to_fields_list(val, field_map, parent))
        else:
            result.append(val)

    return result


def mapped_to_fields(d: dict, field_map: Dict[Tuple[str], str], parent: Tuple[str] = ()) -> dict:
    result = dict()

    for key, val in d.items():
        key_path = parent + (key,)
        replacement_key = field_map.get(key_path, key)

        mapped_val = val
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            mapped_val = mapped_to_fields(val, field_map, key_path)
        elif isinstance(val, list):
            mapped_val = mapped_to_fields_list(val, field_map, key_path + (LIST,))

        result[replacement_key] = mapped_val

    return result
```

- Is the algorithm optimal?
- Does the code adhere to Python standards?
- Is there a better way to encode the replacement scheme?

Comment: This problem statement looks suspiciously similar to [one that was posed in another recent question](/q/277432/9357). Are you two related somehow?

Comment: @200_success I had found this question on reddit originally, and wanted to have my solution reviewed.

Comment: Can you link the Reddit post?

Comment: @Reinderien Unfortunately, it seems to have been deleted.

Comment: That's one of the reasons questions should be self-contained whenever possible.